# IIS 7 ASP.NET Code-Behind Shared Properties Not Initialising

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7, properties, initialization

I have an ASP.NET application which I've recently published to an IIS7 server for testing. I'm  completely new to the whole 'application publishing' and IIS thing, but people at work have been helping me and they're just as stumped by this as I, and google, appears to be.

The problem is with one of my page's property declarations at the top of the code behind, when I try to access one of those properties within, say, the page_load, I get an 'Object not set to an Instance' exception. This only occurs with shared properties, not with standard properties. This is how I'm declaring my properties:

```
Public Shared Property sharedPortalController As New Aurum.Genesis.Adapter.Business.Portal.BusinessLogic.PortalControlClass

Public Shared Property sharedSelectedObjectType As String = "Hello World"
Public Shared Property sharedSelectedMessageGUID As String
Public Shared Property sharedSelectedMessageGUIDs As String()
Public Shared Property sharedXMLDocument As XmlDocument

Public Property xmlIndexCounter As Integer = 0
```

If I were to initialise say, 'sharedSelectedObjectType' as "Hello World" and then apply that value to the text in a label on page load, it throws a 'Object not set...' exception, but if I were to do the same with the xmlIndexCounter and apply it's value to a label, it has no issue at all and the page will load. These errors only occur if I attempt to access or interact with the properties. This is how I'm attempting to interact with my properties in the page load, in this case with the "Hello World" label example:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack = False Then

        ScriptManager.EnablePageMethods = True

        If Session("LockData") = True Then
        sharedPortalController.RecordLockUsername = Session("username")
        sharedPortalController.LockQueueRecords()
            Session("LockData") = False
        Else
            'Do Nothing
        End If

        lblWelcome.Text = lblWelcome.Text + Session("Username")
        lblDepartment.Text = "Genesis " + Session("Department") + " Department Portal"

        lblDepartment.Text = xmlIndexCounter.ToString


        ReBindGridview()
    End If

End Sub
```

It's also worth noting that access to this page is through a login system based on authorisation cookies. The login page behaves absolutely normally with regard to property declarations and usage, whether they're shared or not. Upon successfully validating the user, the login page does a response.redirect to the main menu page, which is the source of the problem.

I'm sorry I'm not able to provide anymore details, purely because I'm quite new to this and I don't really know what further details you might need, so if you require anything else by all means ask and tell me off for not knowing it in the first place! For this reason, I have a sneaking suspicion it will be something really obvious I've missed.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Cheers, Dan